# @QuarkusTest - implementing an interface with annotation @RegisterRestClient, in test - fails the test

Tags: java, testing, cdi, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus `1.2.0.Final`.

I have the following REST client:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "<some key>")
public interface SomeClient {

    @POST
    @Path("<some path>")
    SomeResponse someMethod(SomeRequest request);

}
```

This bean is used in my other beans as a dependency.

And I have the following test case:

```
@QuarkusTest
class SomeTest {
    @Test
    void testGetTransactions() { }
}

class SomeClientImpl implements SomeClient {

    @Override
    public SomeResponse someMethod(SomeRequest request) {
        // <the implementation doesn't matter>
        return null;
    }
}
```

The test is failing with the following exception:

```
Suppressed: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.example.client.SomeClient and qualifiers [@RestClient]
...
```

Why the test is failing? If I remove the class `class SomeClientImpl implements SomeClient {...}` the test is passing. So implementing an interface leads to test failing, which is weird.

---

**Update 1:**

I tried the next code and I'm getting the same exception:

```
@QuarkusTest
class TransactionServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    void testGetTransactions() {
        new SomeClient() {

            @Override
            public SomeResponse someMethod(SomeRequest request) {
                // <the implementation doesn't matter>
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it also fail if you move that class into a separate file?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, it fails

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus REST client is based on MicroProfile REST Client. With MP REST Client you are not supposed to implement the REST Client interface -- it will be automatically generated for you.

For example, if you leave the interface as-is like this:

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "<some key>")
public interface SomeClient {

    @POST
    @Path("<some path>")
    SomeResponse someMethod(SomeRequest request);

}
```

You can use the REST Client like this in your application:

```java
@Inject
@RestClient
SomeClient client;

public void doSomething() {
  SomeRequest req = // ...
  SomeResponse resp = someMethod(req);
}
```

When your application code calls `someMethod(req)` what happens is your application makes an HTTP POST request to whatever URL `SomeClient.someMethod` is configured for, and then the JSON response of that HTTP POST requests is converted into the `SomeResponse` object using JSON-B or Jackson.

For more information, I would suggest going through the [Quarkus REST client guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client)

---

If your goal is mock the external REST service that `SomeClient` normally talks to, I would suggest using a library like [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/) to mock responses to requests by your application via `SomeClient`. In your test, configure the URL for `SomeClient` to point to the MockServer that you start as part of the test.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it doesn't answer my question. Why the test is failing? Is it expected behaviour in quarkus? I know about microprofile and mockserver.

Comment: In CDI you will get a deployment error if not exactly 1 implementation is found for an injection point. I believe what's happening in your error is that 2 implementations are being found: the first impl is being auto-generated by MP rest client and the second impl is the `SomeClientImpl` which you have written. When you remove `SomeClientImpl` then only one impl is found again and the test works as you have observed

Comment: I don't have the same issue with other beans for example: `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` annotated ones. The issue is only with REST clients. According to your assumptions, creating an instance of any bean, should lead to that issue.